# Solving basic trigonometry value using quadrant rule or sum formula

Tags: trigonometry

Basicly, i am bad at mathematics very hard to me got score 70. I try learn trigonometry now, starting from the very basic.
I practice to find the value of $$\sin(135^\circ)$$ using my knowing about $\sin(45^\circ)={\sqrt2\over2}$, $\cos(45^\circ)={\sqrt2 \over 2}$, $\sin(90^\circ)=1$, $\cos(90^\circ)=0$, the quadrant rule and sum angle formula. I hope the expert can help me to correcting and giving a tips.

Using the quadrant rule :
Since $135^\circ$ on second quadrant the sine sign is positive

Using sum formula of sin :
$$\sin(135^\circ)=\sin(90^\circ+45^\circ)$$
$$=\sin(90^\circ)×\cos(45^\circ)+\cos(90^\circ)×\sin(45^\circ)$$
$$=1×\cos(45^\circ)+0×\sin(45^\circ)$$
$$=\cos(45^\circ)+0$$
$$=\cos(45^\circ)$$
$$={\sqrt2\over2}$$
For your informatiom, i am just economic faculty at second semester, and my college tutor giving us a calculus, that contain trigonometry. I need to learn this because 2 weeks again i got calculus examination. Thank you for your support and tips and explanation.

Is my practice is correct ? Can i get the simple way to remember the sum formula of sine and cosine ? What suitable practice for me after i practicing with $135^\circ$ ?

Comment: I know the sum formula and quadrant rule just from the notebook, when my college tutor write it on whiteboard then i copying into my note book.

Comment: $135^\circ$ is an obtuse angle, whose supplementary angle is $45^\circ$. Supplementary angles have the same sines, so $\sin 135^\circ=\sin45^\circ$.

Comment: We need to know the values for $\cos$ and $\sin$ functions for angles between $0°$ and $90°$. The others can be determined by symmetry conditions by the unit circle.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your tips and information. I will searching about supplementary angle and unit circle now.

Comment: @bambangnugroho I've added some related OP! Good work. Bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need in that case use these formula, indeed by the definition of trigonometric function by the unit circle and by symmetry we can directly conclude that:

$$\sin(135^\circ)=\sin(90^\circ+45^\circ)=\sin 45°$$

Refer to the following image ([credits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unit_circle_angles_color.svg)):

[image]

Refer also to the related:

- [What are some must-know trig identities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2657856/505767)
- [How to interpret trig functions in other quadrants?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2649163/505767)
- [Coordinates of a point on a circle - review](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2958425/505767)

Comment: Unit circle, interesting.

Comment: Thank you for your information

Comment: @bambangnugroho That's really all that we need to know for trigonometry. All the formulas can be derived from here.

Comment: Thank you so much i read the article you giving to me, now i am slightly understand.

Answer (score 1):

$135^{\circ}$ is *related* to $45^{\circ}$ because $135^{\circ} = 180^{\circ} -45^{\circ}$ and as such, produces the positive or negative of the ratios concerning $45^{\circ}$.  You don't need to know the compound angle formula to know this.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your information and tips.